# How do I get the exit status for a command invoked with IO.popen?

Tags: ruby

I am using IO.popen to execute a command and am capturing the output like so:

```
process = IO.popen("sudo -u service_user -i start_service.sh") do |io|
    while line = io.gets
      line.chomp!
      process_log_line(line)
    end
  end
```

How can I capture the exit status of *start_service.sh*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can capture the exit status of a command invoked via IO.open() by referencing *$?* as long as you have closed the pipe at the end of your block.

In the example above, you would do:

```
  process = IO.popen("sudo -u service_user -i start_service.sh") do |io|
    while line = io.gets
      line.chomp!
      process_log_line(line)
    end
    io.close
    do_more_stuff if $?.to_i == 0 
  end
```

See [Ruby Core Library entry for IO.popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-popen) for more information.

Comment: Even better: with a block, `popen` automatically closes the file for you at the end of the block, so you can just use `do_more_stuff if $?.to_i == 0` and omit the `io.close`.

Comment: What you usually want is the exit code of the process, not the integer representation of *stat*. So you should use `$?.exitstatus` instead of `$?.to_i`, see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Process/Status.html. Or simply use `$?.success?` if you do not need the value of a non-zero exit code.

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 since `$?` is used inside the block, `io.close` is necessary before one access `$?`.

Comment: As far as I know $? is global variable so you should not expect that $? contains the Process::Status object for the last command.

Comment: second @bibstha, you MUST call `io.close` before inspecting `$?` otherwise `$?.to_i` will always be zero as `nil.to_i` is always zero. to play safe, make sure you use either `$?.exitstatus` or `$?.success?` instead of `$?.to_i == 0`